# Web App with Node and Express Routing and Express-ejs-layout

Tags: node.js, express

I have a server.js file where I require my routing file as below..

```
userRouter      = require('./controllers/user.js');
```

In the server.js file I have routing for home as..

```
server.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('home');
});
```

The home.ejs is put into the layout.ejs body and displays fine. The problem I am having is with the users/new route in the controllers folder..

```
router.get('/new', function(req, res){
    res.render('users/new')
});

router.post('/', function(req, res){
    var newUser = User(req.body.user);
})
```

The code above isnt being injected into the body of the layout.ejs. If I type in the route http://localhost:3000/users/new it works, but its not in the layout.ejs body. How can I fix this?

Also, how can I get my links in the web app to redirect to the correct route; i.e, signup link goes to http://localhost:3000/users/new

Comment: Can you post a fiddle?

Comment: Sorry, Im really new to this. How do I do a fiddle of a Node.js app?

Comment: Sorry lol, I had a brain fart. I was just helping with an angular issue so I was thinking in angular mode. JSfiddle actually doesn't support node (because fiddle is a client side testing setup). You can either post a cloud9 public link, or just a more complete code snippet.

Comment: I actually got it to work! it was an order issue in server.js. Now I just need to link the signup link to the users/new route. How can I do that?

Comment: ```router.post('/new', function(req, res) {``` etc... Then you need to just create an ajax post request to the /new route from the signup page.